# User input to generate new list from .csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I have a question here that I was hoping some kind soul would help answer!

I have a .csv file with three items in the header, and many assigned. The .csv looks like this when printed:

```
['NUTS CODE', 'NUTS NAME', 'Change 2008-2014']
['AT11', 'Burgenland (AT)', '0.6']
['AT12', 'Niederosterreich', '1.4']
['AT13', 'Wien', '2.9']
['AT21', 'Karnten', '2.4']
['AT22', 'Steiermark', '1.1']
['AT31', 'Oberosterreich', '1.3']
['AT32', 'Salzburg', '0.7']
['AT33', 'Tirol', '0.6']
['AT34', 'Vorarlberg', '-0.7']
['BE10', 'Region de Bruxelles-Capitale / Brussels Hoofdstedelijk Gewest', '2.4']
['BE21', 'Prov. Antwerpen', '1.5']
['BE22', 'Prov. Limburg (BE)', '1.2']
['BE23', 'Prov. Oost-Vlaanderen', '0.7']
['BE24', 'Prov. Vlaams-Brabant', '0.8']
['BE25', 'Prov. West-Vlaanderen', '1.5']
```

I want to create a program that takes a user input where the input relates to the first value, say I input : "AT", and the program then returns all the corresponding names and values pertaining to that code. example: If I input "BE" the code creates the following list : 
`[["BE10", "Region de Bruxelles-Capitale / Brussels Hoofdstedelijk Gewest", 2.4], [BE21', 'Prov. Antwerpen', '1.5']]` etc.

This is what I use to open:

```
import csv

with open ('Change_in_Unemployment_2008-2014.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    #next(readCSV)     #Uncomment to remove header

for row in readCSV:
    print(row)

csvfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result = []
user_input = input()
for row in readCSV:
    if row[0].startswith(user_input):
        result.append(row)
print (result)
```

Comment: What if a user entered a string that was not in the row[0], and I wanted to print a message (only once) that states that the data does not exist?
I've tried an else: statement, but it gives me the same message for each iteration through the list, i.e. many many messages.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is almost right, just needs two fixes. You have to skip the header row since thats your column label, and it's better to use raw_input to get user input because input is interpreted as python code.

```
strInput = input("Please enter a full/partial NUTS code to filter by:")
```

Then modify your for loop as follows:

```
header = True
for row in readCSV:
    if header = True:
        print row
        header = False
        continue
    if row[0].startswith(strInput):
        print (row)
```

Comment: Question is tagged `python-3-x`, so `raw_input` and `print` as a statement are incorrect.

Comment: What if a user entered a string that was not in the row[0], and I wanted to print a message (only once) that states that the data does not exist? I've tried an else: statement, but it gives me the same message for each iteration through the list, i.e. many many messages.

Comment: Thanks Mark - just revised the answer to reflect that!

Comment: Joakim - before your for loop, set a variable called found = False. If you find something, then set found = True. After the loop you can check if found is still false, if so, print a messaging saying nothing found.